# removing php extension in htaccess returns an internal server error (500)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a simple **htaccess** script which redirects users to the appropriate page. So, as an example, if the file/folder doesn't exist, a user navigating to `/listing/id` will be shown `listing.php?id=id` instead, or if they navigate to `/username` they will be shown `profile.php?id=username`.

The problem is, when accessing `/listing/id`, I retrieve an internal server error. But not because of the `RewriteRule` that handles this part - but because of the `.php` extension removal part of my **htaccess** script (I figured this out when I commented it out). I have no idea why this isn't working, as I believe I have the correct flags set, and am using the right block of code.

### My Code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# no php extension
# (/listing/id will work if this is commented out, but the other pages won't without the .php extension)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# redirect to www.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

# only allow rewriting to paths that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

# external profile.php?id=$id to /$id
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?id=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# /listing/$id
RewriteRule ^listing/([\w-]+)/?$ listing.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# /$username
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

### Example cases

- `/` (index) *works*
- `/search` *works* (the file exists so it redirects to search page not a user named search)
- `/username` *works* (**username.php** doesn't exist so it redirects to the profile page)
- `/listing/test` returns *Internal Server Error 500* (removing the no PHP extension part of my htacess causes this page to work normally, but now all the others will require `.php` to be appended)

---

All help is appreciated, Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your rules in this order:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to www.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# external profile.php?id=$id to /$id
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?id=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# only allow rewriting to paths that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# /listing/$id
RewriteRule ^listing/([\w-]+)/?$ listing.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# /$username
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```